# I need to find only next line to matched pattern line in multiple log files. I found below awk command on this site

Tags: awk

I need to find only next line to the first matched line in multiple log files. I found below helpful awk command on this site. It prints next line of each matched line. But I need only first match. Please help.

awk '/Linux/{getline; print}' file

cat file
Unix
Linux
Solaris
AIX SCO
Linux
Redhat

above command prints:
Solaris
Redhat

But I need only next line to first matching line: i.e.
Solrais

I can use head command but I think for large files its really not recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use exit after print. It will not keep looping through the file

cat file | awk '/Linux/{getline; print;exit}'

Comment: Thats grt.. got it. Thank you very much :)